# Add Bias to a Matrix in Torch

Tags: lua, torch

In Torch, how do I add a bias vector to each input to when i have a batch input? Suppose I have an input 3*2 matrix (where 2 = number of classes)

```
 A
 0.8191  0.2630
 0.5344  0.4537
 0.7380  0.5885
```

and I want to add the bias value to each element in the output matrix:

```
BIAS:
0.6588  0.6525
```

My final output should look like:

```
1.4779  0.9155
1.1931  1.1063
1.3967  1.2410
```

I am new to Torch and just figuring out the Syntax.

Answer (score 3):

You can expand the bias to have the same dimensions as your input:

`expandedBias=torch.expand(BIAS,3,2)`

yields:

`th> expandedBias
 0.6588  0.6525
 0.6588  0.6525
 0.6588  0.6525`

After that you can simply add them:

`output=A+expandedBias`

to give:

`th> A+expandedBias
 1.4779  0.9155
 1.1931  1.1063
 1.3967  1.2410`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the latest versions of the torch, you do not even need to expand the bias.

you can directly write.

```
output = A + bias
```

The bias matrix will be broadcasted automatically. Check the documentation for the details of broadcasting.
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html